# Share Facebook Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I have a big problem. In my WordPress site sharing on Facebook does not work... I tried everything but did not want to work. The open graph inserts them, they are present, but I do not see nulal if I share on Facebook. Attached what the debugger tells me. I do not want it to be a problem of subdomains or SSL. Until recently it was all.

This is response Debugger Facebook: https://ibb.co/f2ykXz3

Comment: I forgot to put the link of the portal that gives me problems: https://nerdplanet.it/

Comment: That site takes almost _forever_ to load in my browser, and apparently Facebook has the same problem (timeout). Sometimes it works, after re-scraping a URL several times - but mostly, I get timeouts in the debug tool. So you need to make your site faster …

Comment: The link you provided is not in English.

Comment: Maybe better researched over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/